# nanoflann two points equidistance from center

Tags: c++, nearest-neighbor, flann

I'm using nanoflann to find the *k* nearest neighbors (e.g., the *k* closest points to *x*).  Say, I find *k* points and define *r* to be the smallest radius that contains all *k* points.  I then add a new point *y* such that *y* lies on the edge of the ball.  When I again find the *k* closest points to *x*, *y* is **NOT** included.  It seems that nanoflann's default behavior if two points are equidistant from a point is to return the point that was added first.  Is there a way to switch this so it returns the point that was added last?